# Create TimeZone object from timeZoneOffset string?

Tags: swift, timezone-offset

What would be a clean way to initialise a Swift [TimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone) object from timeZoneOffset string of the form: "+HH:MM".

I am looking for something of the form:

```
extension TimeZone {

    init?(UTCOffsetString ofs: String) {

        let signIndex = ofs.firstIndex(of: "+") ?? ofs.firstIndex(of: "-")
        let sign = ofs[signIndex!]

        let separatorIndex = ofs.firstIndex(of: ":")!

        let hhRange = ofs.index(signIndex!, offsetBy: 1)..<separatorIndex
        let hh = ofs[hhRange]

        let mmRange = ofs.index(separatorIndex, offsetBy: 1)..<ofs.index(separatorIndex, offsetBy: 3)
        let mm = ofs[mmRange]

        var offsetInMin = (Int(String(hh))! * 60) + Int(String(mm))!
        if sign == "-" {
            offsetInMin.negate()
        }

        let offsetInSec = offsetInMin * 60
        // Convert string to TimeZone, eg.
        self.init(secondsFromGMT: offsetInSec)
    }

}

let tz = TimeZone.init(UTCOffsetString: "-07:30")
print(tz?.identifier ?? "unknown")
```

The above code block is a correct solution and prints:

> GMT-0730

However I am looking for a cleaner solution where I don't need to extract substrings in order to compute the offset.

Comment: Why would you need this? If you have a timezone and a date just add it to your date string and parse it

Comment: I don't have a date. Just a timeZoneOffset String that I need to convert to TimeZone instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `DateFormatter` which is able to parse the time zone string format. `refZoneString` is the reference to UTC in the current time zone.

```
extension TimeZone {

    init?(UTCOffsetString ofs: String) {
        let refZoneString = "+0000"
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "Z"
        guard let refDate = formatter.date(from: refZoneString),
            let date = formatter.date(from: ofs) else { return nil }
        self.init(secondsFromGMT: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, to: refDate).second!)
    }
}

let tz = TimeZone.init(UTCOffsetString: "-07:30")
print(tz?.identifier ?? "unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Modified it a little and posted here: https://gist.github.com/raunakp/6dff54a3bcc17c76a92d77735c8680d4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by a cleaner but you can combine collection methods `suffix` and `prefix` to avoid the need to use String index to access the desired values:

```
let time = "-02:00"
let hours = Int(time.suffix(5).prefix(2)) ?? 0
let minutes = Int(time.suffix(2)) ?? 0

var offset = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60   
if time.first == "-" { offset = -offset }

print(offset)  // -7200
```